# Is there anything like the For Dummies books for learning AWK?

Tags: linux, bash, awk

Title basically says it all. I'm looking for a relatively easy to understand book on AWK.

Comment: Voting to close since it's a recommendation request, but I learnt from the OReilly book.

Comment: I always liked the [_The AWK Programming Language_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_AWK_Programming_Language). Haven't checked out the [2nd edition](https://awk.dev), yet.

Comment: Get the book Effective AWK Programming, 5th Edition, by Arnold Robins as it covers the features of GNU awk as well as the features of other awk variants such as those described in other books.

Comment: There are learning resources in the tag info: https://stackoverflow.com/tags/awk/info. Also, check out https://ferd.ca/awk-in-20-minutes.html and https://backreference.org/2010/02/10/idiomatic-awk/

Comment: Also see https://grymoire.com/Unix/Awk.html .